# iOS verify app store purchase id by developer

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

How can I check purchase id which was sent by user to me from his orders list?

For example, he can send something like: M1VYXX7VX7 (as written in his purchases list in appstore) and ask to return his purchase (may be he had deleted his app accidentally),

But when I get order information inside of my code (through `SKPaymentTransaction`) I have no access to that identifier. Then only ID i have looks like: 1000000020706713.

So is there any ways to validate that purchase ID using information which was sent to me by app store?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104

Comment: I got it! Thanks, I don't know why, but I was sure I need that short id...

Comment: So does that work for what you're trying to do?

Comment: I will check it soon and then will write the result here

Comment: @PartiallyFinite post it as answer, I will accept it. That worked for me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read [Verifying Store Receipts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104) in the In-App Purchase Programming Guide. According to the documentation:

> To verify the receipt, perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Retrieve the receipt data. On iOS, this is the value of the transaction's transactionReceipt property. On OS X, this is the entire contents of the receipt file inside the application bundle. Encode the receipt data using base64 encoding.
> 2. Create a JSON object with a single key named receipt-data and the string you created in step 1. Your JSON code should look like this:
>
>    ```
>    {
>       "receipt-data" : "(receipt bytes here)"
>    }
>    ```
> 3. Post the JSON object to the App Store using an HTTP POST request. The URL for the store is https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt.
> 4. The response received from the App Store is a JSON object with two keys, status and receipt. It should look something like this:
>
>    ```
>    {
>        "status" : 0,
>        "receipt" : { (receipt here) }
>    }
>    ```
>
> If the value of the status key is 0, this is a valid receipt. If the value is anything other than 0, this receipt is invalid.

Read the article for more details.

Comment: link is broken ):