# is receipt verification necessary for inapp hosted at apple?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I see all these methods to verify the receipts of inapp purchases due to hacking but is it necessary if your content is hosted at apple?

I don't see how a hack on an app can force Apple server to download the content, right?

If the app is free and it is modeled around hosted in-apps you have nothing to worry, correct? I think this is the only case where verification of receipts is not necessary.

Please confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unknown whether Apple does receipt verifications on their end before delivering IAP content, thus you should still probably verify it on your own. It seems that storing a receipt server side for every IAP customer would get pretty troublesome when dealing with billions of receipts, so my guess is they do not verify IAP receipts.

Comment: ok, but do you know how content comes? after the payment is done there at apple, the content is pushed to your device. How would a hacker bypass that? The only information that is entering apple is an apple ID/password and the code of the inapp. The only way I see to fake that is to provide a fake valid AppleID plus a fake credit card. Even if you create your own verification it will not help in that case. What I mean is this: If I am not mistaken, Apple pushes to your app, at the same time, the receipt and the hosted content.

Comment: Don't underestimate hackers. Why not check the receipt periodically, then if flagged as invalid, disable the feature on a code level.

Comment: ok. Just a final question. [By this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17734756/316469), validating a receipt seems to be easy, but recently the thing escalated by using OpenSSL and became giant and complex as hell. So complex that it is impossible to understand, because nobody explains it in detail. Why is that? How do I really implement receipt validation for inapp and bundle on iOS 6 and 7? thanks

Comment: I use the Receigen app (MAS) to generate obfuscated and unique receipt validation code http://receigen.etiemble.com/