# How to save receipt of Apple in-app Purchase in database?

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, in-app-purchase

I'm currently trying to implement an in-app purchase (auto-renewal) into my app.

I would like to save the receipt of each user in my database, in order to have a historic. (as prescribed here: [iOS & Firebase Auto-renewable Subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55343004/ios-firebase-auto-renewable-subscriptions))

My question now is, how do I have to save the receipt? Do I have to save it **encoded** or **decoded**?

I'm using Firebase to do that (Firestore)

Comment: Refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695901/ios-verify-app-store-purchase-id-by-developer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely save the entire encrypted receipt (String). This becomes your source-of-truth since you can continually refresh it with Apple's `/verifyReceipt` endpoint.

You'll most likely also be saving some of the receipt fields (decrypted) that will be updated as you refresh the receipt.

Comment: could you provide 'some of the receipt fields (decrypted)' you store in your database?

Comment: At a minimum you'll probably need `product_id` and `expiration_date` so you can answer the question "Is this user subscribed?". It's better to save everything since you may want to use it in the future: the transaction identifiers will help you understand renewal and churn, the auto-renew status flag is good to understand if annual subscriptions are churning early, etc.